# Insert x rows under a table by a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have researched before posting this and I managed to piece together some code, but for some reason it is not working as I want it to.

I want to add X number of rows under a cell in Excel if its value is changed to something that is greater than 1.

For example, I have a table like this:

```
        Col1            Col2        Col3    Split
   R1  something1      thing2      thing3      2
   R2  something2      thing3      thing4   
   R3  something3      thing4      thing5
```

If I have a value greater than 1 in col4, like 2 in R1 for something1, then my code will insert one row into the table under R1 but it will copy the values from R1, in the end there will be two something1 (because there are two split). So, it will end in something like this:

```
        Col1            Col2        Col3    Split
   R1  something1      thing2     thing3     2
   R2  something1      thing2     thing3     2
   R4  something2      thing3     thing4    
   R5  something3      thing4     thing5
```

Right now, I have this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
    Dim KeyCells As range
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim tRows As Long
    Dim tCols As Long
    Dim miss As Integer

    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableQueryLawson")
    With tbl.DataBodyRange
        tRows = .Rows.Count
        tCols = .Columns.Count
    End With

    col = ColumnNumberByHeader("Splits")

    If col <> 0 Then
        Set KeyCells = range(Cells(5, col), Cells(tRows, col))
    Else
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "Check that column COMMENTS exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If


    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        If Target.Value > 1 Then
            MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."
        End If

            Set newRow = tbl.ListRows.Add()

    End With
    End If
End Sub
```

But, I am stuck at the part of adding a new row and filling down the data that was in the row below. I also need it to be able add to even 10 rows if the user specify so in the Split column.

This is a table with over 10k rows and over 40 columns.

I am using Excel 2013.

Comment: Hi there. A number of folks in our community sometimes say that every time they see gendered assumptions about software engineers, they worry about people feeling excluded. I wonder, could you try to avoid adding male-oriented greetings and pronouns in your posts, so as to make for a more welcoming environment? Thank you.

Comment: Honestly and without any intention of offending, what are you even talking about?

Comment: See my edit, in which I removed "gentlemen" from "This is a table, gentlemen, with over 10k rows". The wording was a bit odd, though - did I misunderstand what you meant?

Comment: Not really, I used gentlemen without trying to offend anybody.

Comment: It's cool, no-one is offended. I am interested in language since I think it is a reflection of how people think, and what their subconscious motivations and biases are. Thus, if there is a corner of (male) brains that says "programmers are male", then this will be reflected in thought processes within the industry, sometimes including in hiring. I like the idea that we can challenge that, even if we sometimes have to question ourselves on how we think (a practice I try to subject myself to also).